# How can I save image from windows phone 8 to firebase server?

Tags: windows-phone-8, firebase

Being an Android app developer, I am new to both Windows phone development and Firebase. I was wondering if I can save an image file (assuming I have the image object) from the windows phone to the firebase database? I am aware that firebase has a REST API so I am guessing I can do it using that. Is this the right method? Any examples? I would appreciate anyone who points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely store images in Firebase, both through the REST API, or through the normal Firebase libraries.

What you need to do is base64 encode the image, and then display it with a dataURL. You can see an example of this approach here:
https://github.com/firebase/firepano

That example uses a FileReader to load in the image client-side using the readAsDataURL() function.

Answer (score 1):

once you have the image, the only options to get them out are the ones exposed by the other side. You said Firebase has REST api, you can use that.. at times REST API is wrapped in a nice lib which makes things easier.

But if you only have REST API, that's what you use