# Manage users with Firebase but store user video in MySQL

Tags: mysql, angularjs, firebase

I am developing an Angular app that uses Firebase to manage users. All is working correctly at this point: users are authenticated via Facebook, FB profile pic is displayed when user is logged-in, etc. the goal of the app is to allow users to upload videos and also vote on videos. I have been pondering the idea of possibly using a MySQL database to store user videos (due to limited storage with the free Firebase account) but I am not sure how feasible this would even be. Has anyone had any experience with something of this nature? I've been browsing the web for some time now but haven't found anything related.

Comment: consider storing files in a file system and sparing the finely tuned db engine of such blobs, showing it its propers. Mysql can point to the pathed file. You can add this to your free service collection: [AWS Free Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I view and store images in firebase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955813/how-can-i-view-and-store-images-in-firebase)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870498/firebase-for-android-send-and-receive-images?s=23|1.8138, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017464/how-can-i-save-image-from-windows-phone-8-to-firebase-server/15031289?s=12|2.2022#15031289, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054575/can-i-store-image-on-firebase-as-file-instead-of-a-dataurl/30055521?s=18|1.9294#30055521,

Comment: All of the links I shared above cover similar topics. The consensus is generally to base64 the images. Note that storing them in MySQL is a bit redundant when using Firebase. If they are too big to be economical, a solution such as GCS or S3 may also be an alternative to MySQL.

Comment: Very good! Thank you for the links, as well as the advice

Answer (score 0):

You don't store videos and images inside a database, you get a storage server, AWS for example, and then save the url to that file in your database. Firebase would be just fine for that.

Comment: This is an opinion, useful for a wide variety of use cases, and I agree in general. But this is not an answer to the question (i.e. how), and is supported by facts or specifics. Storing images in databases is common and must have some merit. It's not as simple as making a sweeping statement that images should not be stored in a database.